# Performance Regression Following Upgrade of MySQL from 5.0 to 5.6

Tags: mysql, upgrade, database-performance

In an intranet Apache/PHP/MySQL web application that has run very well for several years now, I recently undertook an upgrade from 2.2/5.2.5/5.0.x to 2.4/5.5.11/5.6.17 respectively, all on Windows 8.

The most obvious consequence of this upgrade, sadly, has been to notice significant performance bottlenecks at most of my more intensive db queries.

In particular, I have a script that restores an entire db, consisting of over 250 tables, into an empty schema, using `csv` files and `LOAD DATA INFILE...`. Whereas this query used to get done in around one minute, it now takes over 5 minutes, and sometimes much longer.

I have also noticed slow performance during recreation of the tables (using `mysqldump` created script), even prior to loading data.

Apart from about 5 tables which are MyISAM, all others are InnoDB.

The hardware environment is a 'regular' HP laptop with 4GB of RAM and Intel 2.40GHz, dual core with 4 Logical Processors.

My `my.ini` is auto-created during installation (which I have always done using the `windows` executable option from MySQL website. The current configurations are:

```
    [mysqld]

    port=3306
    datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/data/"

    character-set-server=utf8
    default-storage-engine=INNODB
    sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

    log-output=FILE
    general-log=0
    general_log_file="COMPUTERNAME.log"
    slow-query-log=1
    slow_query_log_file="COMPUTERNAME-slow.log"
    long_query_time=10

    log-error="COMPUTERNAME.err"

    max_connections=100

    query_cache_size=0

    table_open_cache=2000
    tmp_table_size=19M
    thread_cache_size=9

    myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
    myisam_sort_buffer_size=36M
    key_buffer_size=8M
    read_buffer_size=64K
    read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
    sort_buffer_size=256K

    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
    innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
    innodb_log_file_size=128M
    innodb_thread_concurrency=9
    innodb_autoextend_increment=64M
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
    innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
    innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
    innodb_open_files=300
    innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
    innodb_file_per_table=1
    innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

    back_log=70
    flush_time=0
    join_buffer_size=512K
    max_allowed_packet=4M
    max_connect_errors=100
    open_files_limit=4110
    query_cache_type=0
    sort_buffer_size=256K

    table_definition_cache=1400
    binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
    sync_master_info=10000
    sync_relay_log=10000
    sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

Please forgive the long question, as I reckon that these details might hold the key to an eventual solution.

Thank you.

Comment: This question should be on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: O yeah? So then how exactly do we migrate it? I'm sorry but its not exactly clear to me right now. Thank you.